# Weird layout with tabBar.topAnchor

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, nslayoutanchor

I have several subviews

```
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    view.addSubview(pageControl)
    view.addSubview((tabBarController?.tabBar)!)
    view.addSubview(skipButton)
    view.addSubview(nextButton)
```

and I tried to layout by means of layoutAnchor. (at this time I anchored pageControl.bottomAnchor to  view.bottomAnchor )

```
   nextButton.anchorWithConstantsToTop(view.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right:
        view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
    nextButtonTopAnchor = nextButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0)
    nextButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    nextButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    skipButton.anchorWithConstantsToTop(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
    skipButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    skipButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    pageControl.anchorWithConstantsToTop(nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 28, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 30)
```

So it works nice and when i rotate device pageControl clamps in a proper place [image]

But if tried to anchor pageControl.bottomAnchor = tabBarController?.tabBar.topAnchor instead of view.bottomAnchor then in portrait orientation everything work ok, but when i rotate device happens something irritating : pageControl goes up[image]

moreover when I get form landscape orientation to portrait orientation back
it remains in upper position [image]

I guess the problem lays in pageControl.bottomAnchor = tabBarController?.tabBar.topAnchor string but i can get why? In landscape orientation still remains tabBar and pageControl still had to anchor it to tabBar's topAnchor. Please maybe someone do know whats going on with that behavior?

Comment: Have you tried setting the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false on all the views you are adding? If you don't set this to false there can be weird behavior sometimes.  You might also need to call layoutIfNeeded when changing constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this line:

> view.addSubview((tabBarController?.tabBar)!)

You shouldn't do that. Please remove it and then set up your constraints after the current view controller has been added to the `UITabBarController`. A sample candidate for this would be the first time the `viewWillAppear` is executed.

If you `pageControl` is created programmatically then you should also set its `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to `false` (as pointed out in the comments). If the control is created in a storyboard this step isn't necessary.